# I installed py2cytoscape and it's working fine with GUI in pycharm linux but when I run my code from termial then this problem:

Tags: python, ubuntu, cytoscape

$ python ../any.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "../any.py", line 1, in 
   from py2cytoscape.data.cyrest_client import CyRestClient

File "/home/admin-cbdm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2cytoscape/data/cyrest_client.py", line 4, in 
    from .network_client import NetworkClient

File "/home/admin-cbdm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2cytoscape/data/network_client.py", line 12, in 
    from ..util import util_dataframe as df_util

File "/home/admin-cbdm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2cytoscape/util/util_dataframe.py", line 88
    row = (source, itr, target, *extra_values)
                                ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Is this the problem with the path?

Comment: Please add your code, this path won't help much. If you want help with your problem, you will have to provide more information and not just the error log...

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal environment is not the same that you have on pycharm.

Make sure you have the latest Python 3 or Python 2.7.13 on the terminal (`which python` and start `python` to make sure you are accessing the correct version) then install py2cytoscape (also make sure you are accessing the corresponding `which pip`).